# Why can't vscode find `preLaunchTask`?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using `vscode` to debug a typescript program. Below is the configuration. It has a `preLaunchTask` to use the task to build the code before debugging. when I run debugger, it prompts an error dialog `Could not find the task 'build'`. It fails to find the `build` task which is already defined in `tasks` section. How can I make it work in vscode?

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node/src/index.ts",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/node/dist/**/*.js"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "yarn build"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom tasks should be in a **separate** *tasks.json* file, not in the same *launch.json* file.

From the docs on [*launch.json* attributes](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes):

> - `preLaunchTask` - to launch a task before the start of a debug
>     session, set this attribute to the name of a task specified in
>     [tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) (in the workspace's `.vscode` folder).

See the VS Code tutorial on creating [Tasks Auto-Detection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_task-autodetection) and [Custom Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks).

[image]
[image]